# How do I debug across application restarts in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm building a Visual Basic application in Visual Studio 2010. Some of my options can only be applied on restarting the application.

I have not gotten a single crash when application is running normally. Nor does it crash when I apply settings, manually exit and restart. On the other hand, as soon as I try to do a automatic restart from the application, I get an exception on one out of 5-10 restarts.

I've tried to run the debugger, but as soon as the application restarts, the Visual Studio debugger is turned off and does not turn back on when the application launches again. Nor does it launch again with same configurations. It seems the debugger launched application configuration and the manually launched application configuration files are different.

Is there a way I can get around this? Keep the debugger on across restarts? Or should I undertake a different strategy?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you running Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I'm don't really trust anything Microsoft has put out after 2013. My App's aimed for Windows 7 and below, so getting VS 2013+ is not necessary.

Comment: Quality of life improvements alone would be worth it.  As to your question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167610/how-to-attach-visual-studio-to-a-process-that-is-not-started-yet) should show you how to attach to a process as it starts up.

Comment: What do you mean by Quality of life? As in the later VSs are easier to use, better designed, less buggy? Thanks for the link, I'll have a read through it. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1: Attaching the debugger from within the application

If the application sometimes crashes at startup add a call to [**`Debugger.Launch()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) in the application's [**`Startup` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup(v=vs.110).aspx). Doing so will cause Visual Studio to open a window where you can choose to attach its debugger.

You can check the [**`Debugger.IsAttached` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to determine whether a debugger is already attached or not.

Steps to subscribe to the `Startup` event:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Properties`.
2. Go to the `Application` tab.
3. Press `View Application Events`.
4. Select `MyApplication (events)` in the left combo box.
5. Select `Startup` in the right combo box.

Code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

...

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    If Debugger.IsAttached = False Then
        Debugger.Launch()
    End If
End Sub
```

### Method 2: Letting Windows start the debugger, which in turn starts your application

An alternative solution is to add your application to the *Image File Execution Options* registry key, which allows you to specify a debugger which should launch the application for you.

**NOTE:** Adding your application to *Image File Execution Options* causes Windows to automatically launch the specified debugger ***instead*** of your application whenever you try to open it. Your application's path is passed as a command line argument and it is then up to the debugger to launch your application, attaching itself to it.

[Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) have some info about *Image File Execution Options* on their blog: [***An introduction to Image File Execution Options***](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/).

Here's how you'd do it:

1. Open *Regedit*.
2. Navigate to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` key.
3. Locate the key with the name of your application (if it exists), or create a new one in the format of `yourApplicationName.exe`.
4. Create a new `String` value (`REG_SZ`) and name it `debugger`.
5. Set the value of `debugger` to `vsjitdebugger.exe`.
6. Go ahead and start debugging!

For more information see: [**How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically - MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.100).aspx)