# pass arguments to elevated command prompt started from wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd, command-prompt

The scenario is to start elevated cmd which calls a bat file and right after starting the process the app quits.
The code from the wpf app:

```
private static void CmdCommand(string filename, string workingDir)
{
  var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(workingDir + filename);
  processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  processInfo.Verb = "runas";
  processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
  processInfo.Arguments = "\""+workingDir+"\"" ;
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    delegate
    {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
      {
        Process.Start(processInfo);
      }));
    }));
  t1.Start();
  Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    delegate
    {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
      {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
      }));
    }));
  t2.Start();
}
```

The code in the bat file:

```
set Path1=%~1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
copy /Y "%Path1%dbg\lib.dll" "%Path1%lib.dll"
pause
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
call "%Path1%wpf.exe"
```

The result is that the cmd appears for a moment and disappears and no result.
This works when not elevated. But I need it to be elevated as there are no rights to copy in the working dir.
I tried recording screen to pause when the cmd appears but the recorder scips this part.
So how can I debbug it?

EDIT

Actually it is working but without one line

```
processInfo.Arguments = "\""+workingDir+"\"" ;
```

and I need to pass the arguments

EDIT 2

Apparently the problem is """ but if I don't add those I'll have a bug with paths containing spaces.

Comment: This one might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167610/how-do-i-attach-visual-studio-to-a-process-that-is-not-started-yet

Comment: Did you look in event viewer? Have you considered doing this copying using csharp in the app instead?  You could force the app to require admin privileges using the manifest.

Comment: You checked the user has admin rights on this pc?

Comment: I want to avoid elevating app itself and the app is using the file copied so I can't do it from the app.

Comment: I don't understand why, if you're using a high level programming language, you need to run a batch file to simply copy a file, and run an executable file, (with a delay in between)! Please explain what you mean by "the app is using the file".

Comment: Additionally, why are you creating a variable, 1. ```@Copy /Y "%~1dbg\lib.dll" "%~1"```, 2. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL```, 3. ```@Start "" "%~1wpf.exe"```.

Comment: @Compo The app loads the lib and uses functionality with import.