# How to attach debug to a process that has not started yet?

Tags: visual-studio

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167610), but there is a twist.

I need to debug a process that is within a DLL, not an executable. The caller is a java application which I have no control over, so I cannot start my debug session from there.

Can it be done?

Comment: The process can't be inside the DLL. The functions provided by the DLL will become a part of your java application process, which is your debug target. If you have control over the DLL, then you can place some hooks, infinite loops and such in the points of interest and have the process to hang there till you attach the debugger and release it.

Comment: We'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have no control over the Java portion of the code, I created a debug attach point by displaying a `MessageBox` at the point I needed the debug to start.

This gives me time to attach the debug.