# cant debug using __asm int 3 or DebugBreak or __debugbreak() on win7 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-7, debugbreak

i cant launch the visual studio 2008 debugger by using **_*asm int 3***, or **_debugbreak()**, or **DebugBreak()**. I am trying to debug a C++ DLL by embedding "__asm int 3;" in it, build the project and replace the generated dll with the one that is launched by an exe. I cant start that exe from visual studio 2008 itself, because the exe is launched by another program, that i have no control over. I have windows 7 64 bit. Please Help.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6677161/968261) useful.

Comment: Something wrong with the machine's WER setup (Windows Error Reporting) or the just-in-time debugger setup (Aedebug registry key).  Still an unpleasant way to get the debugger launched, you'll want to create a better debugging scenario.